# manage user log for full system in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i am using codeigniter,want to manage audit log for user from full system.

if any user after login perform add,update or delete operations then need to insert that query in log table.

### EX :

if abc user is login. and add another sub user then need to database entry like

abc user is login and had added xyz subuser. also last inserted id with table name.

---

i have tried firestick library but it's also not good for us.

is it possible to manage this ?

any suggestions,

any help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create a method in your `MY_Model` that logs transactions and simply call that method at the end of any desired operation?

So after your `$this->db->insert()`, you call the `$this->logAction()` method?

Comment: Thanks for reply but this solution i already know. but i want global function like using hooks,benchmark or else and getting direct query in particular function and  i do not want to put code after each insert,update or delete in my particular models